# Reliable/persistent outbound sockets needed, options?

Tags: java, sockets, scala, netty, nio

I have a Scala application which maintains (or tries to) TCP connections to various servers for hours (possibly > 24) at a time. Each server sends a short, ~30 character message about twice a second. These messages are fed into an iteratee where they are parsed and eventually end up making state changes to a database.

If any of these connections fail for any reason, my app needs to continually try to reconnect until I specify otherwise. Any messages getting lost is Bad. I have no control over the servers I connect to, or the protocols used.

It is conceivable there would be as many as 300 of these connections at once. No exactly a high-load scenario, so I don't think NIO is needed, though it might be nice to have? Other bits of the app are high-load.

I'm looking for some sort of socket controller / manager which can keep these connections as reliably as possible. I am running my own blocking controller now, but as I'm inexperienced with socket coding (and all the various settings, options, timeouts, etc.) I doubt its will achieve the best possible uptime. Plus I may need SSL support at some point down the line.

Would NIO offer any real advantages?

Would Netty be the best choice here? I've seen the Uptime example [here](http://static.netty.io/3.5/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/uptime/package-summary.html), and was thinking of simply duplicating it, but being new to lower-level networking I wasn't sure if there were better options.

Comment: Detecting disconnections and reconnecting should be trivial even with java.net.Socket.

Comment: I think you are looking for a reliable messaging service actually. Have a look at the various implementations of JMS.

Comment: Yes it is trivial; as I mentioned above I've got something working. However I'm uncertain of the best strategies for ensuring as few packets are lost as possible, and assumed this would be a "solved" problem in one library or another. I suppose a lot of it would come down to a timeout guessing strategy? Close and re-open a socket too early and you've lost whatever packets were en-route.

Comment: EJP, I have no control over the servers I connect to. So unless there's another way to adapt JMS to a generic TCP stream I don't think it will work.

Answer (score 1):

> However I'm uncertain of the best strategies for ensuring as few packets are lost as possible, and assumed this would be a "solved" problem in one library or another.

Yup.  JMS is an example.

> I suppose a lot of it would come down to a timeout guessing strategy? Close and re-open a socket too early and you've lost whatever packets were en-route.

That is correct.  That approach is not going to be reliable, especially if connections go up and down regularly.

A real solution involves having the other end keep track of what it has received, and letting the sender know when then connection is re-established.  If that can't be done, you have no real way of controlling how much gets lost.  (This is what the reliable messaging services do ...)

> I have no control over the servers I connect to. So unless there's another way to adapt JMS to a generic TCP stream I don't think it will work.

Yup.  And the same applies if you try to implement this by hand.  The other end has to cooperate.

I guess you could construct something where you run (say) a JMS end point on each of the remote servers, and have the endpoint use UNIX domain sockets or loopback (i.e. 127.0.0.1) to talk to the server.  But you still have potential for message loss.

Comment: I wasn't thinking I'd find a way to preserve 100% of messages without some server-side logic. I was just hoping to find someone who'd tackled this problem before and had a solution to minimize the loss, is all. Anyway, thanks for pointing me towards JMS; if I can something on the servers it sounds like that'd be the thing to use.